# What is returned when making the comparison between 2 columns of the same dataframe, when using dataframe.iloc?

Tags: pandas

I am not pretty sure about what is returned when making a condition inside a dataframe.iloc function. I have the next code line:

-> df1.**loc**[(df1['Date'] >= df2['StartDate']) & (df1['Date'] <= df2['EndDate'])]

For what I've seen this code line will return all the rows that meet the condition above. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the output you can expect:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv")
print(df1)

         Date
0  2019-07-19
1  2019-07-21
2  2019-07-31

df2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv")
print(df2)

    StartDate     EndDate
0  2019-07-01  2019-07-10
1  2019-07-30  2019-07-20
2  2019-07-31  2019-07-31

df = df1.loc[(df1['Date'] >= df2['StartDate']) & (df1['Date'] <= df2['EndDate'])]
print(df)

         Date
2  2019-07-31
```

Comment: Thank you Soumendra!
I thought that code line was going to return all the rows of the dataframe df1, according to the condition.
I mean:
Column Date, and the others columns that meet the condition.

Comment: It is Ok.
but what if the dataframe has another columns, not only the Date one?
In that case should return all the other values of the columns that are aligned (same row #) of the date that meet the condition, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Additional columns from `df1` will be returned and not from `df2`